# Jquery for followers not triggering

Tags: jquery, django

I want to add the following functionality to a site but need Jquery to change the following to unfollow and vice-versa. Everything seems fine but it's not working. (All the links to jquery work perfectly and load)

**Jquery for the functionality**

```
$('a.follow').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.post('{% url "user_follow" %}',
        {
            id: $(this).data('id'),
            action: $(this).data('action')
        },

        function(data){
        if(data['status'] == 'ok' ){var previous_action == $('a.follow').data('action');
            console.log(previous_action);
        // toggle data_action
        $('a.follow').data('action', previous_action == 'follow' ? 'unfollow' : 'follow');

        // toggle link text 
        $('a.follow').text(previous_action =='follow' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow');

        // update followers 
        var previous_followers = parseInt($('span.count .total').text());
        $('span.count .total').text(previous_action == 'follow' ? previous_followers + 1 : previous_followers - 1);

        }
    }
    )

    

});
```

**HTML**

```
{% with total_followers=user.followers.count %}
        <span class="count">
            <span class="total">{{ total_followers }}</span>
            follower{{ total_followers|pluralize }}
        </span>
        <a href="" data-id="{{ user.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in user.followers.all %}un{% endif %}follow" class="follow btn">
            {% if request.user not in user.followers.all %}
            Follow
            {% else %}
            Unfollow
            {% endif %}
        </a>
{% endwith %}
```

**view for on jquery request**

```
@login_required
def user_follow(request):
    user_id = request.POST.get('id')
    action = request.POST.get('action')

    if user_id and action:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
            if action == 'follow':
                Contact.objects.get_or_create(
                    user_from=request.user,
                    user_to=user
                )
            
            else:
                Contact.objects.filter(user_from=request.user, user_to=user).delete()
            
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
        
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error'})

    return JsonResponse({'status': 'error'})
```

**Last note**
There is a jquery for the like button above the followers' jquery object don't know if its presence has any effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targetting all `.follow` class instead you can keep value i.e : `this` inside some variable and then use it inside your callback . Then , you need to compare value using `.text().trim()` this will give you `Unfollow` or `Follow` depending on this change your `.follow` class text.Lastly ,to set correct count to your `total` span you can use `prev('span').find('.total')` then change total value .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('a.follow').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var selector = $(this) //declare this outside your ajax
  /* $.post('{% url "user_follow" %}', {
       id: $(this).data('id'),
       action: $(this).data('action')
     },

     function(data) {
       if (data['status'] == 'ok') {*/
  //get text of a tag and trim it(to remove any white spaces)
  var previous_action = selector.text().trim()
  console.log(previous_action);
  // toggle
  selector.data('action', previous_action == 'Follow' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow');

  selector.text(previous_action == 'Follow' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow');
  //get the span(total) using prev(.count)->find('total')
  var previous_followers = parseInt($(selector).prev('span').find('.total').text());
  //change the span total value
  $(selector).prev('span').find('.total').text(previous_action == 'Follow' ? previous_followers + 1 : previous_followers - 1);

  /* }
    }
  )*/



});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="count">
            <span class="total">12</span>follower
</span>
<a href="" data-id="{{ user.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in user.followers.all %}un{% endif %}follow" class="follow btn">   Follow </a>
<br>
<span class="count">
            <span class="total">23</span> follower
</span>
<a href="" data-id="{{ user.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in user.followers.all %}un{% endif %}follow" class="follow btn">   Unfollow </a><br>
<span class="count">
            <span class="total">17</span> follower
</span>
<a href="" data-id="{{ user.id }}" data-action="{% if request.user in user.followers.all %}un{% endif %}follow" class="follow btn">   Follow </a>
```

Comment: came through again :)

Comment: glad i helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is not triggering the change because you try to change one element using a class selector.
Try triggering the change, with the same selector that you capture the data.

```
    // toggle data_action
    $(this).data('action', previous_action == 'follow' ? 'unfollow' : 'follow');

    // toggle link text 
    $(this).text(previous_action =='follow' ? 'Unfollow' : 'Follow');
```